# Get full order information - Wazala API

Tags: xml, api, e-commerce

I am trying to use the Wazala API to get the full order information for all orders (or even one) for a store. [This is the format](http://www.wazala.com/api/docs/order-forward/) that I need. The page mentions using the method `OrderVerify('OrderID')` but gives no indication how that method is to be used with the API.

The 'get_orders' method on [this page](http://www.wazala.com/api/docs/admin/) works great, but it is a very simple summary listing of orders, and doesn't have all the information needed to process an order (i.e. billing/shipping address, line items, etc.).

Is there an API call for Wazala that retrieves full order info in the XML format [shown here](http://www.wazala.com/api/docs/order-forward/), if so, how is it called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Received this response from Wazala support today:

> The only REST request that returns your store orders list is the get_orders call.

So currently the answer to my question is: no.

I am still not sure what the OrderVerify method can be used for, though apparently it cannot be used with the API. As a side note, I received this from them regarding any "update" functionality for the API:

> While you can pull data from Wazala using our outbound API, however at this time there is not an inbound API.